# Downloading a single file, from a large github enterprise repo, efficiently, with Octokit (c#, .net)

Tags: git, github, github-enterprise, octokit, octokit.net

I am trying to download a single file from github enterprise, given the URL, in C#, with OctoKit. This is the head version from master (or the default branch).

I want to do the equivalent of:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: token INSERTACCESSTOKENHERE' -H 'Accept:application/vnd.github.v3.raw' -O -L https://private.github.enterprise.com/repos/owner/repo/contents/path/foo.txt
```

I have found a way to do this, but the repo is extremely large and it takes a long time. The reason is, I have to spider the entire tree in order to find the identifiers for the specific files that I want.

```
Uri url = new Uri(URL);
String trans_fullname = String.Format("/{0}/", repo.FullName);
String basePath = url.AbsolutePath.Replace(trans_fullname, "");

/* this, and the linq line, are what is taking all the time */

var cannotuseawait = client.Git.Tree.GetRecursive(repo.Id, "heads/master" );
cannotuseawait.Wait();
TreeResponse tree = cannotuseawait.Result;

/* searching through a lot of items!!!!! */

TreeItem Found = (from foo in tree.Tree where foo.Path.Contains(basePath) select foo).SingleOrDefault<TreeItem>();
var fwait = client.Git.Blob.Get(Repo.Id, Found.Sha);
fwait.wait();
var contents_64 = fwait.Result;
```

Again, this takes over 4 minutes because our repository is so huge. While, the curl command above is relatively instant... so, I know there is a way. I would prefer not to abandon Octokit, since I have other functionality in the project that already works with it.

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out, in the client.Repository.Content object there are methods called things like UpdateFile, GetReadMe, DeleteFile, CreateFile, but there is no "GetFile".

But, counter intuitively (at least for me), there is a function called "GetAllContents", which normally, as one would expect, gets all the contents for a repo. But, one of the overloads takes a path as a parameter, so you can limit it to a file. I will limit expression of my frustration here and just say that this is not intuitive.

```
        var cannotuseawait = client.Repository.Content.GetAllContents(Repo.Id, basePath);
        cannotuseawait.Wait();
        var res = cannotuseawait.Result;
```